# Swift Imageview wont load correct image from feed

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview, cell, feed

It appears my loop seems to load all the images taken from a feed into the image view but sets only the very last image from the feed into all cells I'm not sure how to stop this and grab a image for each cell and set it. I'm new to swift and I've sorta jumped right in to programming.. heres the code of interest any help is appreciated

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BlogPost

    let blogPost: BlogPost = blogPosts[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = blogPost.postTitle
   // cell.textLabel?.text = blogPost.postImageLink
   // if cell.postImage?.image == nil {
//  let cache = ImageLoadingWithCache()
//  cache.getImage(cell.postImageLink,  imageView: cell.postImage,     defaultImage: "IMG_0079")
    if  cell.postImage?.image == nil {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

            // retrieve image from url
            let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:self.postImageLink)!)!)
            self.imageArray.append(image!)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { Void in
                // set image in main thread
                guard indexPath.row < self.imageArray.count else { return }

                cell.postImage?.image =  self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
            })

    }
    }
```

blog class

```
class BlogPost: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var postImage: UIImageView!
var postTitle: String = String()
var postLink: String = String()
var postImageLink: String = String()
 @IBOutlet weak var postLabel: NSLayoutConstraint!
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: Is `BlogPost` a custom type or is it a subclass of `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: @Aaron custom i believe so, ill add my class

Comment: Ask yourself what "async" _means_...

Comment: and what is `blogPosts`?

Comment: custom cell @ aaron.. @matt ill try a different way of caching images and see if that'll work

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to dequeue a cell and then set the properties to another of the same custom cells. Wherever you're setting the data on each cell in the `blogPosts` array you should just assign that data to the dequeued `cell`.